# Lock orientation for one form in delphi xe6

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

Anyway to lock orientation to per se Portrait for only a specific form and not the whole application?
Using Delphi xe6, for iOS. Can't seem to find anything by googling. Thank you!

Update:

My underlying issue is that I'm using a zbar unit for scanning and when the screen rotates, the display from the camera view does not. So the app goes to landscape, but the view from the scanner is still portrait, thus making the view look sideways. From what I've googled and tooled around on my own, it appears that locking the orientation maybe easier so here is where I am.

I've found this article: http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/s/84941, but to no avail, the one form I don't want to rotate, still rotates.

I've implemented this code for the time being, although I'm not very found of it. Was just a quick, fix work-around.. I put everything ontop of a layout and on the form's resize event:

```
  with LayoutOrientation do
  begin
    if Clientwidth > ClientHeight then
    begin
      Align := TAlignLayout.None;
      width := ClientHeight;
      height := Clientwidth;
      RotationAngle := 90;
      RotationCenter.X := 0.948;
    end else begin
      RotationAngle := 0;
      RotationCenter.X := 0.5;
      Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
    end;
  end;
```

Meh, I don't like this because the app still repaints when it doesn't need to and also the status bar showing at the top still, gives it a funky look. This for the time being works - but really looks like I hacked it, which in this case I did..

Comment: Have you checked out the AndroidApi's for delphi. You can probably do it by handling the native android code. I have no experience with that though

Comment: I am developing for iOS as the question stated.

Comment: Then probably the iOSApi's. Sorry that i can't help more

Comment: Not sure if you ever found a solution to this, but maybe a few changes to what I did here could give you your desired effect/behaviour I only use one form tough http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387402/delphi-firemonkey-change-ios-screen-rotation-at-runtime

Answer (score -1):

Update Application.FormFactor.Orientations before and after showing your form.

```
  Application.FormFactor.Orientations := [TFormOrientation.Portrait];
  ScannerForm.ShowModal;
  Application.FormFactor.Orientations := [TFormOrientation.Portrait, TFormOrientation.Landscape, TFormOrientation.InvertedLandscape];
```

Comment: Doesn't work... So for example, I'm in landscape, then when I go to open the scan form, that form to is in landscape, but this time won't change orientation. It's as if it thinks it's already in portrait so it locks that orientation.

Comment: Or adjusting code around, a different scenario is, if i open the form while already in landscape, the scan form appears in landscape, but then if I rotate device to portait, it will then lock into portrait, but only will once I rotate it to portrait. I've tried the forms invalidate() method but to no avail

Answer (score -2):

It actually depends how do you generally controll your application orientation.

If you use Layouts to control orientation you could force the use of same layour for every oriantation.

If you are creating different forms for different orientation you can force your application to use same for for every orientation.

Comment: I'm using different forms and layouts within the forms.

Comment: This doesn't really help me out though, How do I begin to go about forcing orientation for individual layouts/forms?