# Screen orientation on iOS

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

Per [this question](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/programming-languages/f/delphi-language/67640/screen-orientation-problem-with-tchart-in-delphi-10-3-rio/84157#84157) in Delphi an FMX app can be selectively forced into landscape or portrait with code like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Chart1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Application.FormFactor.Orientations = [TScreenOrientation.Landscape] then
     Application.FormFactor.Orientations := [TScreenOrientation.Portrait]
  else
     Application.FormFactor.Orientations := [TScreenOrientation.Landscape];
  end;
end;
```

I can't figure out how to translate this code above to C++Builder.  I tried the following code based [on this post](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=686057) but it gives access violation on both iOS and Android:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
 _di_IInterface Intf;
 if (TPlatformServices::Current->SupportsPlatformService(__uuidof(IFMXScreenService), Intf))
 {
 _di_IFMXScreenService ScreenService = Intf;
 TScreenOrientations Orientation;
 Orientation << TScreenOrientation::Landscape;
 ScreenService->SetScreenOrientation(Orientation);
 }
}
```

Is this even doable in FMX with C++Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

`if (TPlatformServices::Current->SupportsPlatformService(__uuidof(IFMXScreenService), Intf))`

should be this instead:

`if (TPlatformServices::Current->SupportsPlatformService(__uuidof(IFMXScreenService), &Intf))`

Note the addition of the `&` operator in the last parameter.  This is even stated in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.TPlatformServices.SupportsPlatformService):

> Note: Please consider that you need to add & before Intf, as you can see in the code sample above.

Also, `Intf` really should be declared to match the interface you are requesting, eg:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    _di_IFMXScreenService ScreenService;
    if (TPlatformServices::Current->SupportsPlatformService(__uuidof(IFMXScreenService), &ScreenService))
    {
        TScreenOrientations Orientation;
        Orientation << TScreenOrientation::Landscape;
        ScreenService->SetScreenOrientation(Orientation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dang, thanks Remy.  The code works now (without access violation) but nothing happens.  I put a `ShowMessage` inside the if block and it is firing.  Just doesn't change the screen orientation (testing on iOS).

Comment: Related: [Delphi/Firemonkey Change iOS screen rotation at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387402/), and [Change iOS screen rotation at runtime](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/1796-firemonkey-change-ios-screen-rotation-at-runtime/)

Comment: Thanks Remy - that last link you gave makes me think this is bad approach on my part - and i just need to do without ability to set orientation (build app differently).