# Delphi Form - force Screen orientation on Windows Surface

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, landscape, delphi-10.3-rio

Today I have an app that forces  landscape on iPad and Android.

How can I do the same on Windows Surface?

I'm using Delphi 10.3.3 Rio.

```pascal
// Rotate 270 IPAD
{$IFDEF IOS}
ChangeiOSorientation(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,TScreenOrientation.Landscape,TScreenOrientation.InvertedLandscape]);
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF ANDROID}
Application.FormFactor.Orientations := [TScreenOrientation.Landscape];
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: For reference for other readers, `ChangeiOSorientation()` probably came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33631096/65863). Did you two using `Application.FormFactor.Orientations` on Windows? Does it not work?

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's not implemented on Windows

Comment: Please refer to: https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/changing-screen-orientation-programmatically-using-delphi/