# Delphi Firemonkey IOS screen orientation landscape App Store Release Error

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In Delphi, select Project - Options - Orientation - Application - Enable Custom orientation

In the process of distributing to the App Store after ipa release in Application Store mode by checking Landscape home right

An error occurs as below...

When testing before deployment, it works fine on the device, but this error occurs during the App Store deployment process.

Package Summary:

1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:

/var/folders/lq/y1lq4mqx4b11mzmd5g0fqq1h0000gn/T/DFCFBCE4-0289-48CA-ABF7-F5C73681FA6D/1558603491.itmsp - Error Messages:

ERROR ITMS-90474: "Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires these orientations: 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight'. Found 'UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight' in bundle ''."

I tried the following in code, but if I switch the screen with the iPhone screen rotation lock unlocked, it is fixed.

It doesn't start horizontally on first run

Application.formfactor.orientations := [TScreenOrientation.landscape,TScreenOrientation.invertedlandscape];

[Delphi/Firemonkey Change iOS screen rotation at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387402/delphi-firemonkey-change-ios-screen-rotation-at-runtime)

I followed the link above, but it still doesn't work.

If anyone knows, please reply!!

environment :
Window 10
Delphi 10.4.2
PAServer 21.0
macOS BigSur 11.2

Comment: If you disable some orientations by using Custom Orientations, you need to add a UIRequiresFullScreen key to the Version Info, with a value of: true

Comment: Thnak you  Dave Nottage :) it has been resolved.